# What mysql data type for radio buttons?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a form with radio buttons  (see http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/3c6Mc/) and users are submitting data mostly through radio buttons. What "type" will the values for the radio buttons have to be/should they be in the mysql table?

The fields advocacy, drafting, interview etc will all be either "pass" or "fail" on the webform, so what do I do in the database?

```
CREATE TABLE `shoutbox`(  
    `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
    `instructor` varchar(25) NOT NULL ,  
    `secretmessage` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
    `advocacy`     NOT NULL, 
    `drafting`     NOT NULL, 
    `interview`
    `letter`
    `solicitor`
    `barrister`
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
);
```

**Boolean**

If I use a Boolean, do I set the values for Pass and Fail to 1 and 0?

```
    <tr>  

        <td><label>Interview</label></td>  
        <td><input type="radio" name="interview" value="1" /> Pass</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="interview" value="0" /> Fail</td>  
    </tr>
```

with this mysql?

```
    CREATE TABLE `shoutbox`(  
   `interview` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
```

**TinyINT**

If I use a TinyInt, do I also set the value of Pass and Fail to 1 and 0?

```
             <tr>  

                <td><label>Interview</label></td>  
                <td><input type="radio" name="interview" value="1" /> Pass</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="interview" value="0" /> Fail</td>  
            </tr>


    CREATE TABLE `shoutbox`(  
   `interview` TINYINT NOT NULL,
```

**ENUM**

If I use enum, do I set the value to "pass" and "fail" and then use the same names in the database with enum?

```
 <td><label>Interview</label></td>  
  <td><input type="radio" name="interview" value="pass" /> Pass</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="interview" value="fail" /> Fail</td>  
</tr>
```

Mysql

```
            CREATE TABLE `shoutbox`(  
           `interview` enum('pass', 'fail') NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Radio buttons usually fit an enum type best.

Comment: tinyint or Enum if you want something more then 0 and 1 but "pass" and "fail"

Comment: I've updated the OP, if i use boolean, do I set the "value" in the form field to 1 and 0 and then have to remember what those numbers represent in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ENUM may be behave unexpectedly if inserting integer values.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `shoutbox`(  
`interview` enum('pass', 'fail') NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO shoutbox (0); // this would be equivalent to an empty ENUM value ('')
INSERT INTO shoutbox (1); // represents 'pass', 2 represents 'fail'
INSERT INTO shoutbox ('pass'); // works as expected, same for 'fail'.
```

If you used ENUM, it would be best to validate the radio input value so that no empty or invalid strings are passed.

```
$interview = in_array($_POST['interview'], array('pass', 'fail')) ? $_POST['interview'] : 'fail';
```

I recommend using an BOOLEAN or TINYINT and validating the radio input value by using intval();

```
CREATE TABLE `shoutbox`(  
`interview` tinyint(1) NOT NULL);
```

php:

```
$interview = intval($_POST['interview']); // sets interview to 0 or 1
// "insert into shoutbox($interview);"
```

Comment: If you do it using "intval", what should the value or name be set to in the actual form? should it use "1" and "0" or can intval turn words into numbers? You say intval sets interview to 0 or 1, but what is interview set to before it gets changed to 0 or 1?

Comment: the name for the radio should be 'interview' and the value should be "0" or "1". Intval converts a string into an integer to prevent sql injection.

Comment: thanks, but if the interview value is "O" and "1", isn't that already an integer? so why does intval need to convert? Or are the values "O" and "1" actually strings that just look like integers?

Comment: __"0"__ is a string type, and __0__ is an integer type. It's good practice to explicitly convert any submitted data (the radio value) to the corresponding sql data type before inserting into the database to prevent inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of this in terms of what the radio buttons represent in the real world.

The answer is probably that they represent a short list of mutually exclusive things.  Generally those are represented in a business object with an enum, which can be saved most space-efficiently as a tinyint in the database.

A [tinyint][1] can represent values from -128 to 127, so works for up to 256 different values (assuming your language can map enum values to negative numbers) or up to 128 different values if your enums are restricted to non-negative numbers.  If you have more different values (which would make for a hard-to-use UI), you could step up to a smallint.

For things that only have two values, you still won't get more efficient than using a tinyint (short of mapping multiple questions into different bit positions of a numeric field, which I strongly discourage under all but the most extreme conditions).  MySQL does support a [`bit` data type][2] that supports bit fields, but I doubt that bit(1) would still not use less storage than tinyint (it should use the same amount, but I could not find a specific reference).

EDIT:

Regarding your edit asking about how to use the MySQL enum datatype, I actually do not recommend it's use if you have a business logic layer.  The reason for that is that you need to maintain the enum definition in two places (the business object and the DDL for MySQL).  So, I would go with your Tinyint example.  I would also have the business layer generate the values into your UI rather than hard coding them.

Using the Boolean data type is clearer if you genuinely have a Boolean condition.  However, right now you have a list of values that will "only ever have two values".  Experience shows that truth will change during the lifetime of your program more often than you might expect (maybe "Pass" and "Fail" gets additional values like "Incomplete Interview" or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated the OP. If I use TINYINT, do I set the "value" on the form to an integer and then just remember what the digit represents in the tiny int column of the database? If you have a moment, do you mind looking at the OP again...

Comment: thanks, I should say that I'm not a real developer so it's a little unclear what you mean when you say have to business layer generate the values into your UI...

Comment: @Michael: A common development pattern is to have the UI code talk to business objects, and have the business objects talk to the database. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture.  You ever only want to define things in one place to simplify maintenance and reduce the chance of errors.  If you don't know how to make a business layer, it's probably good enough to "remember" what the 0's and 1's stand for.  If you are consistent everywhere in your UI, you should be fine.  If you're not using a business object layer, you can probably use MySQL enums instead of tinyint.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `enum` type would back a radio set best, but since your options are pass / fail, you could use `bool`.

Comment: thanks for your help, I've updated the OP. If I use Boolean, do I have to set the "value"s on the form to either 1 or 0? but if I use Enum, I set the value on the webform to the same name that is in the enum fields?